# Create a dock like application using C# and wpf

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I need to create a application which is similar to those we will get when we buy a laptop. It will be visible only when the mouse pointer reaches the top of the window. So how can I able to do this using C# 4.0  ?
http://www.notebookcheck.net/uploads/pics/win2_12.jpg
this link u can see the application. I need to create such type
Any idea pls share. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose there are several different ways to achieve this effect:

- You can place part of the window of your application above the visible screen, so only a part of it is visible (let's say you can see only it's bottom). Then you need to handle events when mouse enters (`MouseEnter`) and leaves (`MouseLeave`) the form to move the form up and down.
- You can use a background thread to call `GetCursorPos` method at a set interval (i.e. each 500ms) second to check where currently the mouse is. See this link for more information about it and a sample code: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getcursorpos. 
  (If you need only to check the mouse position, you can use a timer to simplify you application.)

Answer (score 1):

When you hit what's possible with C#, you can always start invoking native code - such as the windows API. Since you don't ask a specific question, I'll leave you with:

- Position your app where you want it to appear and hide it.
- Capture mouse position with windows api (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750056/how-to-capture-the-screen-and-mouse-pointer-using-windows-apis))
- When mouse is at screen corner / top, etc; make your app visible.

Now make sure all this works with dual screen setup, and you are done.