# .NET - Capturing cursor bitmap at specific coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cursor, interop

### DISCLAIMER

This question is somewhat similar to another on StackOverflow, [C# - Capturing the Mouse cursor image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918990/c-sharp-capturing-the-mouse-cursor-image) - but with a slightly different requirement.

### BACKGROUND

- I am writing a scriptable automation client that scraps data from 3 legacy Win32 systems.
- Two of these systems may indicate the presence of finished tasks via a change in cursor bitmap when the cursor is hovered over some specific areas. No other hints (color change, status message) are offered.
- My own code is derived from the original post mentioned on the disclaimer.

### REQUIREMENTS

- While I an able to capture the cursor bitmaps by programatically moving the cursor to a specific coordinate and capturing it via CURSORINFO, the idea was to allow an interactive user to continue using the computer. As it is, the forced positioning disrupts the process.

### QUESTION

- Is there a way to capture the cursor bitmap by parametrized position (e.g., request the CURSORINFO as if the focus was in window W at coordinates X, Y)?

Comment: You can use this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750056/how-to-capture-the-screen-and-mouse-pointer-using-windows-apis

Comment: Thank you for the (extremely) quick reply, @Zz. Nonetheless, I'm afraid the issue stands - the GetCursorInfo function only reports the current cursor position and its associated info, bitmap included. My specific requirement involves obtaining the cursor info at a given coordinate. If i misunderstood (or misread) the linked entry, I would appreciate if you could point it out to me.

Comment: I am sure you will find your answer here :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can't do this without causing visual artifacts.  You can fake the WM_NCHITTEST and WM_SETCURSOR messages with some hope that the program will use the mouse position passed in WM_NCHITTEST.  The cursor will however change and you have to restore it.  That is very visible and very ugly.  This is a feature you don't want to have to implement.

Comment: I'll check on WM_NCHITTEST, @Hans, thanks for pointing it out. About the feature implementation, for a process POV I can't agree more - I'd rather import data directly to a buffer on the new unified system and create an interface where the user could consolidate everything. But a custom storage for the legacy apps and sheer curiosity made me wonder: 'Is that arbitrary bitmap capture even possible?' =)

Comment: Addendum: @Hans, it worked the way you mentioned - artifacts included. Since it fulfills the question, would you mind to post a reply so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: I'll skip, I like happy answers.  You could just post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution fulfilling the specifics of this question was implemented using the information provided by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), so all credit must go to him.

The current setup is as shown:

[image: Environment definition]

It runs on a machine with two displays. Not shown in the picture is a small application that is actually responsible for the event monitoring and data scraping - it runs minimized and unattended.

### Solution

- Obtain the Window handle for the application to be tested (in this case, I cycled through all processes returned by **Process.GetProcesses**():

  ```
      IntPtr _probeHwnd;
      var _procs = Process.GetProcesses();

      foreach (var item in _procs)
      {
          if (item.MainWindowTitle == "WinApp#1")
          {
              _probeHwnd= item.MainWindowHandle;
              break;
          }
      }
  ```
- With the window handle for the target application, we are now able to craft specific messages and send to it via **[SendMessage](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html)**.
- In order to pass coordinates to SendMessage we need to serialize both X and Y coordinates into a single long value:

  ```
  public int MakeLong(short lowPart, short highPart)
  {
      return (int)(((ushort)lowPart) | (uint)(highPart << 16)); 
  }
  ```
- Knowing the specific coordinates we want to probe (_probeX,_probeY), now we can issue a WM_NCHITTEST message:

  ```
  SendMessage(_probeHwnd, WM_NCHITTEST, NULL, (LPARAM)MakeLong(_probeX, _probeY));
  ```
- We need **[GetCursorInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetCursorInfo.html)** to obtain the Bitmap:

  ```
  Win32Stuff.CURSORINFO ci = new Win32Stuff.CURSORINFO();
  Win32Stuff.GetCursorInfo(ci);
  ```
- Check if the return flag from GetCursorInfo indicates that the cursor is showing (pco.flags == CURSOR_SHOWING):
- Use **[CopyIcon](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/CopyIcon.html)** in order to obtain a valid handle for the cursor bitmap:

  ```
  IntPtr hicon = default(IntPtr);
  hicon = Win32Stuff.CopyIcon(ci.hCursor);
  ```
- Use **[GetIconInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetIconInfo.html)** to extract the information from the handler:

  ```
  Win32Stuff.ICONINFO icInfo = default(Win32Stuff.ICONINFO);
  Win32Stuff.GetIconInfo(hicon, icInfo);
  ```
- Use the **System.Drawing.Icon** class to obtain a manageable copy using Icon.FromHandle, passing the value returned by **CopyIcon**;

  ```
  Icon ic = Icon.FromHandle(hicon);
  ```
- Extract the bitmap via Icon.ToBitmap method.

  ```
  Bitmap bmp = ic.ToBitmap();
  ```

### Limitations

- This solution was tested on two different OSes: Windows XP and Windows 8. **It only worked on Windows XP**. On Windows 8 the cursor would flicker and return to the 'correct' format immediately, and the the captured CURSORINFO reflected that.
- The test point areas must be visible (i.e., application must not be minimized, and test points can't be under an overlapping window. Tested window may be partially overlapped, though - and it doesn't need to have focus.)
- When **WM_NCHITTEST** is issued, the current physical cursor over WebApp changes to whatever cursor bitmap is set by the probed application. **CURSORINFO** contains the cursor bitmap set by the probed application, but the coordinates always indicate the 'physical' location.