# Get the windows machines keyboard cursor (Caret position) position globally using c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, mainframe

I have created a win forms application to capture the keyboard events globally.But I couldn't capture a valid keyboard cursor position when I am running a mainframe TN3270 emulator in my machine. Any way to capture the valid keyboard cursor position of TN3270 emulator on windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167722/net-capturing-cursor-bitmap-at-specific-coordinates is this what your looking for?

Comment: @Req404 Thanks for your help. Actually I have already did the things for capturing the courser position. But when I am opening the TN3270 emulator on windows giving a invalid keyboard courser position(Position of courser when we are typing),