# How to capture Mouse Pointer through VB .Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have written code in vb .net to take a screenshot of the screen.  It captures the screen, but it doesn't capture mouse pointer.  My code is below

```
Private Sub Take_Clip()

    Dim graph As Graphics
    Dim bnd As Rectangle = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds

    Dim SS As Bitmap
    SS = New Bitmap(bnd.Width, bnd.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(SS)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bnd.Size)

End Sub
```

How to modify this code to capture mouse pointer also?

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  If you want a cursor in the image then you have to draw it yourself.  Use the Cursor.Draw() method.

Comment: @HansPassant : `Cursor.Draw()` will just draw the default cursor, not the currently active one. You can get around this by using a few WinAPI calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include mouse cursor in screen capture using SharpDX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163667/include-mouse-cursor-in-screen-capture-using-sharpdx)

Comment: The answer in the duplicate above is written using the regular .NET methods, so just ignore the fact that the question is about SharpDX. :)